# How can i make gui for yolov5 load from pytorch and opencv to tkinker?

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface, tkinter, yolov5

Please help im not understand how to make gui for realtime detection using yolo with tkinker as gui. And how to render bounding box from pytorch to tkinker ?

Here is the code :

```
import torch

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import numpy as np
import cv2

model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s', pretrained=True)


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()  
    result = model(frame)
    cv2.imshow('Screen', np.squeeze(result.render()))
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xff == ord('x'):
        break
    if cv2.getWindowProperty("Screen", cv2.WND_PROP_VISIBLE) <1:
        break
        
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You need namespace import tkinter. Here is link [link] https://www.tutorialspoint.com/using-opencv-with-tkinter

Comment: did you know how to render the bounding box from the model ?

Comment: I don't use torch.